# Verify two shapes are equal in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm about to create small challenge for my team which is similar with challenge honeycomb candy in series Squid Game of Netflix.

The idea is user will use mouse click to make a dot around a shape, then i will use api of canvas context to draw another shape from those dots.
Example:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("CANVAS")), context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
  // all points are given as x (from left to right), y (from top to bottom)
  context.moveTo(10, 20); // x = 10 (10 px from the left edge of the canvas), y = 20 (20 px from the top edge of the canvas)
  context.lineTo(100, 97); // x = 100, y = 97
  context.lineTo(50, 105); // x = 50, y = 100

context.stroke();
```

finally i will compare this shape with the original shape, if they're same then user win.
anybody know how to compare two shape are same in js? or i need to compare each of dot of two shapes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to compare shapes that are drawn on the canvas.
One possibility would be to store information about shape in const or array(with all shapes) and read the data of the shape that has been created by the user.

Suggested steps :

- get your standard shape coordinates
- get the coordinates of the points done by the user
- compute the figure bounding box (min/max on x/y basically).
- draw the shape and fill it with color (on hidden canvas)
- set globalCompositeOperation of context to xor, and draw what would be the standard figure on this canvas.

```js
<canvas id="visibleCanvas" width="630" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="hiddenCanvas" width="630" height="500" style="display:none;"></canvas>
//later in code
hiddenContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
```

that should create similar output:

### [image]

```js
ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh);
```

of the canvas and count pixels.

- compute the number out of non-null pixels. Generally speaking the more empty pixels the better the score is

Here is perfect art about canvas globalComposite operations https://techglimpse.com/canvas-types-source-destination-operations/

Comment: it look promise, i will try. thanks a lot